# PredictionIO - getting error when build and run Evaluation metrics

Tags: classification, evaluation, predictionio

I followed this quickstart:

https://docs.prediction.io/templates/classification/quickstart/

and this document for evaluation metrics

https://docs.prediction.io/evaluation/paramtuning/

Everything seems ok until the step build and run evaluation metrics

pio eval org.template.classification.AccuracyEvaluation \
    org.template.classification.EngineParamsList 
I am getting the exception:
Exception in thread "main" scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object org.template.classification.AccuracyEvaluation not found.
    at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.notFound(MissingRequirementError.scala:17)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.ensureModuleSymbol(Mirrors.scala:126)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.staticModule(Mirrors.scala:161)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.staticModule(Mirrors.scala:21)
    at io.prediction.workflow.WorkflowUtils$.getEvaluation(WorkflowUtils.scala:103)
    at io.prediction.workflow.CreateWorkflow$$anonfun$19.apply(CreateWorkflow.scala:146)
    at io.prediction.workflow.CreateWorkflow$$anonfun$19.apply(CreateWorkflow.scala:144)
Could anyone help me with this?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the exact same problem. Fixed it by doing the following:

For each .scala file in engine_dir/src/main/scala/org/template/**engine_name**/ you need to change the first line from...

```
package <SomeTemplateName>
```

To the following (replacing **engine_name** with the name of the folder in the path mentioned above):

```
package org.template.<engine_name>
```

Then, in engine.json you need to change the following line...

```
"engineFactory": "<template name>.<template engine>",
```

To the following (once again replacing **engine_name** with the name of the folder in the path mentioned above):

```
"engineFactory": "org.template.<engine name>.<template engine>",
```

Now re-run...

```
pio build
pio train
pio deploy
```

Then you should be able to run the model evaluation without errors.

Comment: Thank you Rob, it's really help.

Answer (score 0):

Simply run it like this

> $ pio eval org.example.classification.AccuracyEvaluation   \
>       org.example.classification.EngineParamsList

You dont have to change anything. The class package from the sample was **org.example.classification** not **org.template.classification**